# Android ContentObserver onChange() only returns false

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, calllog, android-context

I'm trying to implement a ContentObserver for CallLog.Calls content provider. I mean, If I make a call, or receive a call, etc, the observer must notify me that the CallLog.Calls content provider has changed. But the onchange method only returns false, even with the observers registered, and notified. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

This is my code. It's an Activity.

```
package com.psyhclo;


public class RatedCalls extends ListActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCallsObserver";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private RatedCallsContentObserver callsObserver = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private CallDataHelper dh = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(RatedCalls.this);

class RatedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public RatedCallsContentObserver(Handler h) {
        super(h);
    }

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RatedCallsContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange
                + ")");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerContentObservers();
    fillList(); 
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    registerContentObservers();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    unregisterContentObservers();

}

private void fillList() {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

    cursor.setNotificationUri(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);

    dh = new CallDataHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int numberColumnId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int durationId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int contactNameId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int dateId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int numTypeId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);
    // int contactIdColumnId =
    // cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);

    Date dt = new Date();
    int hours = dt.getHours();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
    String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    ArrayList<String> callList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(contactNameId);
            String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
            String callDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateId);
            String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("contact_id", 1);
            values.put("contact_name", contactName);
            values.put("number_type", numType);
            values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
            values.put("duration", duration);
            values.put("date", callDate);
            values.put("current_time", currTime);
            values.put("cont", 1);

            getBaseContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null);
            this.db.insert(CallDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            callList.add("Contact Number: " + contactNumber
                    + "\nContact Name: " + contactName + "\nDuration: "
                    + duration + "\nDate: " + callDate);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem,
            callList));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

private void registerContentObservers() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    callsObserver = new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler);
    cr.registerContentObserver(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            true, callsObserver);
}

private void unregisterContentObservers() {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    if (callsObserver != null) { // just paranoia
        cr.unregisterContentObserver(callsObserver);
        callsObserver = null;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer for this question.

[Android onChange() method only returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431710/android-onchange-method-only-returns-false)